# Randomize Slides in Elementor Slider

Tags: slider, elementor

If possible randomize order in Sliders in Elementor Slider?

I can find this script. I add this code in html before slider, but it doesn´t work.

````
(function(){
let parent = document.querySelector('.elementor-slides');
let images = parent.children;
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
while (images.length) {
frag.appendChild(images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]);
}
parent.appendChild(frag);
}());
</script> ```
````